# Teams from different project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project X and a org wide documentation project Y in Azure DevOps services. Work Items in the documentation project Y need to tag members from project X. But looks like this can't be done because members of X are not members of the documentation project.

Therefore, I am trying to add engineering folks team say 'Team XDev' from project X into the documentation project Y. But even there I get an error like so:

[image]

So, my question is how can I provide access to 'Team XDev' from project X in project Y? I don't want to do it member wise because of obvious reasons related to maintainability.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage an organization level security group, add the members from Project B to it (individually) and use that group in project A. You can't reference Project scoped security groups directly from one team to another nor in an organization level security group.

You can find the docs here:

- [About permissions and groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page%2Ccurrent-page)

Comment: can you please share a reference from the docs on this? And how do I create a organization level security group? Is it under Organization -> Security -> Permissions -> New Group?